# mongodb find between dates (month, year)

Tags: mongodb, find

I have a collection with two fields, similar to the one bellow:

> {
>     year: 2017,
>     month: 04 }

How can i select documents between 2017/07 - 2018/04?

Answer (score 1):

Solved with:

```
db.collection.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $addFields: {
                "date": {
                   "$dateFromParts": {
                   "year": "$year",
                   "month": {"$toInt": "$month"}
                 }
                }
            }
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $match: {
             "date": {
                 "$gte": ISODate("2017-07-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
                 "$lte": ISODate("2018-04-30T00:00:00.000Z")
               }
            }
        },

    ]
);
```

Comment: above answer is different with this?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to make sure you db is **storing date in ISO** format ( *a format that mongo supports )*

You can use following command to find documents :-

```
model.find({
  date:{
   $gte:ISODate("2017-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
   $lte:ISODate("2017-07-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
  }
})
```

> Where model is the name of the collection and date is a attribute of
>   document holding dates in ISO format.